# Не загружается песня на сайт php

Tags: php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST' action=''>
<h2>Выложить песню</h2>
<input type='file' accept='.mp3' name='audio'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Выложить песню'>

echo var_dump($name = $_FILES['audio']['name']); 
echo var_dump($tmp_name = $_FILES['audio']['tmp_name']);
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, 'audio', $name);
```

Не загружаются аудио файлы, с картинками все работает tmp_name пустой ""

Comment: ковыряйте конфиг на макс. размер аплоад, стоит небось какое нить 5мбайт, а песня больше

Comment: ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20000M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '20000M'); 
Забыл это указать, стоит в том же файле

Comment: Проверьте поле ключ `$_FILES['audio']['error']`, выясните причину именно такого значения.